Carry of a SOFR swap
This might be a stupid question, but I'm wondering about the following. The SOFR swaps are usually structured to make regular payments on a yearly basis, fixed for floating. The fixed rate is simply the agreed coupon rate. However, the floating rate will be the compounded SOFR rate over that year that is not know in advance. My understanding is, that the carry of a swap is calculated as the the difference of the next fixed and floating payment. But since I don't know the floating yet, is there a concept of carry for these swaps? One could take implied fwd rates from the market, but that would not accurately count as carry as this might change. Thanks for claryfication

Is your question USD-specific? Would the carry differ for a swap leg set in arrears from, e.g. €STR / SONIA / SARON?

@DimitriVulis It is not USD-specific. I've just chosen the most common known case, e.g. SOFR :)

Is there a concept of carry for financial contracts that don't carry funding cost? If so, how would it look like?

No. I don't define the "carry" of a swap like this. Not on the job, and not in my book (Pricing and Trading Interest Rate Derivatives: a practical guide to swaps). Actually I claim that IRS like this (as paper contracts) have an expected cost-of-carry of zero. (Roll-down is another calculation entirely).
The value to which you refer, which I have no name for, in my view, is a useless metric, and I have never used it.
Suppose you look at the current US SOFR curve:
1y: 4.15%
2y: 3.84%
3y: 3.74%
1y1y: 3.52%

If you receive a 2y swap at 3.84%, the "difference between that and the first (1y) period" is -31bps. What does this indicate? Not a whole lot other than the second half of the swap must have expected lower rates to recoup the initial cash outflow. And it does: the 1y1y is 3.52%.
If you receive a 3y swap at 3.74%, the "difference between that and the first (1y) period" is -41bps. Again, very little additional information.
You can get the same amount of information by asking the question: what are the expected net cashflows on these swaps? (approximately)
2Y (1mm notional): -3.25k, +3.25k
3Y (1mm notional): -4.2k, +2.1k, +2.1k
You don't lose (or earn) money simply due to the first cashflow. You have to factor in the whole curve.

But other sources, e.g. bloomberg does state "carrry" for swaps. Do you think that is non-sense?

As I also state in my publication "carry" said by some people is actually what I refer to as "roll-down", some people say "carry-roll". Some people say "carry" and have another definition. I don't know what bloomberg is doing. I'm actually quite practical about it. I just define it for use in my book and readily acknowledge that you may come across different or opposing definitions. But I am, at least, consistent in my own terminology. Try asking Bloomberg about their calculations.

Thanks for your comment. It seems Bloomberg also differentiates between carry and roll down. Carry for them is simply fwd rate - spot rate.

Let's take the carry of a 10y sofr swap with a horizon of 1y.
This would be 1y9y - 10y = (10y -1y) x dv01 (1y)/ dv01 (1y9y)
If the carry were not exactly this number I could either pay 1y9y rec 10y or vice versa and make money for free.
There is no difference between this and a LIBOR swap for eg, as you can lock the 1y spot start swap in today in this example (approx as the first fixing is already known in a 1y spot start swap)
